# Redirect is not working in the Accounts.createUser()

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router, react-router-dom

I have used react-router-dom in the meteorJS. I have tried to redirect after creating the account. Now account has created successfully but redirect is not working.

I am also tried to setState add in when account created successfully. It's also not working.

```
   handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Accounts.createUser(
            {
                username: this.state.mobile,
                password: "123"
            },
            function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("err", err);
                } else {
                    console.log("account created");
                    this.setState({
                        redirect: true
                    });
                    return <Redirect to="/" />;
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

**This message showing in the console**

`Exception in delivering result of invoking 'createUser': TypeError: this.setState is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you lost context

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let that = this;
    Accounts.createUser(
        {
            username: this.state.mobile,
            password: "123"
        },
        function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("err", err);
            } else {
                console.log("account created");
                that.setState({
                    redirect: true
                });
                return <Redirect to="/" />;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the callback to your current context, you can do it by using an arrow function.

In addition that return statement inside the callback doesn't do what you think is doing, that value is lost, you should be pushing the new route using the history object

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  Accounts.createUser(
  {
    username: this.state.mobile,
    password: "123"
  },
  err => { // here use the arrow function to bind to the current "this"
    if (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
    } else {
      console.log("account created");
      this.setState({
        redirect: true
      });
      hashHistory.push("/"); // push the next route
    }
  });
}
```